Bash сравнение переменных с $RANDOM
Есть код:
read -p "Выбери число от 0 до 5: " $number
rand=$(($RANDOM%6))
if (( $(bc <<< "$rand -eq $nubmer") )); then
    echo "Не повезло"
fi

При разных значениях переменных number и rand блок if все равно выполняется
Вероятно, все кроется в преобразовании типов данных, но я могу ошибаться

Были ошибки в синтаксисе и именах переменных
read -p "Выбери число от 0 до 5: " number
rand=$(($RANDOM%6))
echo Выпало $rand
if [[ $rand -eq $number ]]; then
    echo "Повезло"
else
    echo "Не повезло"
fi

admin1@astra:~$ sh ~/bash/rand1.sh
Выбери число от 0 до 5: 4
Выпало 1
Не повезло

admin1@astra:~$ sh ~/bash/rand1.sh
Выбери число от 0 до 5: 4
Выпало 4
Повезло


Большое спасибо!
